# CSS TranslateX(-50%) not working as expected

Tags: css

TranslateX(-50%) instead of placing the element(.heading) in the center places it on the extreme left

```
.heading {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try `position:absolute`...

Comment: `position: relative;` does not change a block level element's behaviour of grabbing as much width as available. `position: absolute;` makes it so the element only grabs as much width as needed for the content - which is what you want. You can achieve the same width behaviour by setting `display: inline-block;` if `position: absolute;` shows undesirable results. The question remains, though: Why are you not simply using `text-align: center:`?

Comment: To help you better, provide a real code snippet that you can attach in your post. In other words, add HTML as well (and get rid of the vendor prefix).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three options depending on what you want to achieve:

- `position: absolute;`, center an element both vertically and horizontally without taking any space in the normal flow of the document.
- `position: relative` and `display: inline-block;`, center an element both vertically and horizontally taking space in the normal flow of the document as if it was in its normal spot.
- `text-align: center;`, center an inline element.

---

### Absolute positioning:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
.heading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  Heading
</div>
```

---

### Relative positioning and inline element retaining its block characteristics:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
.heading {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  Heading
</div>
```

---

### Text align center:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
.heading {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  Heading
</div>
```

---

**Notes:**

- Use the shorthand function `translate()`.
- **Always** add the property without vendor prefixes below.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks